# Flutter: cannot find symbol MethodCallHandler

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to get my Flutter app to receive data from other apps via iOS/Android sharing dialogs. Basically I want to be able to receive http links.
While there are a couple of plugins that allow to share from Flutter, I can't seem to find anything when it comes to receiving data (at least not cross-platform).
I've been working through this [example](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) from the official Flutter documentation, but it doesn't work.
MainActivity.java throws the exception "cannot find symbol MethodCallHandler".

```
MainActivity.java:

package com.example.flutterlink;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.ActivityLifecycleListener;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  private String sharedText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
      if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
      }
    }

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "app.channel.shared.data").setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
                  result.success(sharedText);
                  sharedText = null;
                }
              }
            });
  }

  void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
  }
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: OK, it's actually quite simple: the code in the documentation is missing an import.

`import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;` still don't know how to achive the same thing on iOS though

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) was updated a few days ago and now includes the missing import `import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;`